# How do I split string using `if` condition and separator

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a variable in javascript with text separated with commas, for example:

`var array = "hello,goodbye,test1,test2,1,90m tall";` [NO SPACE AFTER COMMAS]

If I use `.split(',');` the result is as follows:

```
array[0] = hello
array[1] = goodbye
array[2] = test1 
array[3] = test2
array[4] = 1
array[5] = 90m tall
```

But I want this:

```
array[0] = hello
array[1] = goodbye
array[2] = test1 
array[3] = test2
array[4] = 1,90m tall
```

How can I do it? I can imagine I have to add some special restriction but I don't know how...I also checked regex but...no success.

Comment: Use a . Instead of , for numbers?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's just an example, in real life it's a big variable with long text (500KB, > 9000lines) so I can't just replace it with `.`

Comment: Use the `, ` answers, but only if you can guarantee that's how the commas are separated.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I edited the main post, it's my fault, no spaces after comma!

Comment: You're going to have to change the format of the big variable. Instead of comma separated values, use JSON.

Comment: In the future make sure you use real code. You just invalidated 2 answers that *were* correct and that's not cool.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I'm sorry, the answers arrived very fast and I have not had time to edit my mistakes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what the logic is by which you want to split or not split. If for instance you don't want to split by a comma that has at least two digits following it, then this will do it:

```
array.split(/,(?!\d\d)/))
```

This performs a negative look ahead for two digits, and will only match commas which do not have these digits following them.

Snippet:

```js
var array = "hello,goodbye,test1,test2,1,90m tall";

document.body.innerHTML = array.split(/,(?!\d\d)/)
                               .join('<br>');
```

### Follow up question/answer

You asked in comments how to split this:

```
[hello]blabla,[how,are,you]xx,[i'm fine]
```

So that a comma would only split if it were followed by an opening bracket.

For this you use positive look ahead (`?=`):

```js
var array = "[hello]blabla,[how,are,you]xx,[i'm fine]";

document.body.innerHTML = array.split(/,(?=\[)/)
                               .join('<br>');
```

Comment: I'm looking for a regex similar, but instead of only 2 digits, I want only match comma which do not have digits or any char.

For example: `var array = "hello,goodbye,test1,test2,some text with,comma in the middle";` This is another possible scenario.

Then the result should be: `array[4] = some text with,comma in the middle`

Comment: If you do that then the comma after `test2` will not be split either (if it is followed by `,1,90`. Is this what you want? Please be very exact. *comma which do not have* ... is not clear. Do you mean before or after? You were clear in your question, but what you say here would not solve the problem you put in the question.

Comment: More simple: each sentence have `[ ]` symbol at the beggining.

For example: `var array = "[hello]blabla,[how,are,you]xx,[i'm fine]";`

Expected result: `array[0] = [hello]blabla, array[1] = [how,are,you]xx, array[2] = [i'm fine] `

So I want to split the text ONLY if after comma, there is a '[' symbol.

Comment: Well, that is a different question. You would split by `/,(?=\[)/`, where you do a positive lookahead, meaning the bracket must follow the comma, otherwise it is not a splitting comma.

Comment: Exactly! Awesome, do you use any tool for regex? It's working now.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.split(', ')` (note the included space)

Edit: Based on your change to the question, trincot's solution does what you're asking for.

Here's a JSFiddle to prove it: https://jsfiddle.net/ea2mdgpj/

Comment: It's not working because the string it's not separated with spaces, I'm gonna edit the main post. It's my fault, I'm sorry.

Comment: Ah. Then you have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the string really has spaces after each comma-separated field, just change the split call:

```
.split(', ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like,

```
var array = "hello,goodbye,test1,test2,1,90m tall";
array = array.split(",");
array.push(array.splice(array.length - 1).join(","));
```

And now console.log(array) will be,

```
["hello", "goodbye", "test1", "test2", "1,90m tall"]
```

Concept behind the logic,

- split the string by using the delimiter `,`
- detach the last two cells from the array using splice.
- attach the detached part into the original array by joining with `,`

Comment: What if there are elements after the 90m tall element in other rows?

Comment: @NidhinDavid OP might have a pattern for his array. If the array that he given is his constant pattern then this code would work.

Answer (score 0):

`var array = "hello, goodbye, test1, test2, 1,90m tall";`

Add the spaces and use .split(', '), or use  dots ('.') for numbers instead of commas (',')

Comment: I wish, but is not that simple.